# How to group data in a table (tableau)

Tags: tableau-api

I have a table, which contains the sum of different values. you can see in the pic attached that the Filling Method equals to FM-Paper and FM-Electronic. How can I show it so that it is visually more attractive?

[image]

Comment: I suggest use of background color. Every group with their own color where sum has more intensity of color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Caveat:** There is some risk in the format of your data - double counting values. Considering this is just for *display purposes only*, here's what I'd suggest:

Creating a visual where users are able to intuitively realize that one or more categories are a subset of another category is the goal. (Tableau does this natively when the data is shaped correctly.)

To mimic a subcategory, create a calculated field like so:

```
If [Category] = 'FM-Paper' or [Category] = 'FM-Electronic' Then
STR('       ') + [Category]
Else [Category]
END
```

This simply adds space before the two 'sub-categories.' If it looks better or is better understood, you could also do something like '*****' or '---->'.

[image]

You could take this a step further and remove the parent category if not needed - leaving only the 'sub-category' by doing replacing your values with a calculated field:

```
IF [Category] = 'Filling Method' Then NULL
Else [Value]
END
```

[image]